# Webdriver io, загрузка файла через input type="file"

Tags: javascript, input, selenium-webdriver, coffeescript

Я пишу тесты на **CoffeeScript** с использованием **Webdriver.io** и **mocha**. Код обрабатывается с помощью компилятора CoffeeScript.

В процессе работы мне нужно было загрузить файл на сервер с помощью элемента ***input type="file"*** (display: none).

Я пытаюсь передать адрес файла следующим образом (естественно, предварительно делая его видимым: style.display = 'block'):

```
elem_input = $('div.class_1 input.class_2')
browser.elementSendKeys(elem_input.elementId, '/home/user/ ... /test.txt')
```

Файл найти не удается, в консоли выходит сообщение об ошибке **"File not found"**.

Внимательно проверил путь, он корректный. Если загружать файл непосредственно через интерфейс, вручную, тоже никаких проблем не возникает.

В чём может быть причина такой ситуации и какие могут быть варианты решения проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_path = browser.uploadFile(FILE_PATH) # Путь к загружаемому файлу на устройстве
$('div.my_selector').setValue(file_path)